# How to adjust one of the bar's label in histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My codes is here

```
Yr = c("2016","2017","2016","2017","2016","2017")
Type = c("A","A","B","B","C","C")
Value = c(73,183,160,476,11,73)
Percentage = c(29.92,25.00,65.57,65.03,4.51,9.97)
p1Data <- data.frame(Yr,Type,Value,Percentage)

library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(p1Data, aes(Type, Value, fill = Yr)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Value, paste(Percentage, "%"), sep = "\n"), y = Value), size = 4, vjust = 1.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  ggtitle("2016 V.S. 2017")  +
  labs(fill = "Catagory")
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you actually want the labels to be? Do you only want the one that's cut off to be moved, or all of them?

Comment: ...and technically that's not a histogram, just a barplot

Comment: @alistaire want to put that label in the top of the bar~ 
hahaha ~ I am just a beginner for R thanks for your comment to let me know that it's only a barplot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `vjust = 1.5` to `vjust = "inwards"` in your `geom_text`.

```
ggplot(p1Data, aes(Type, Value, fill = Yr)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Value, paste(Percentage, "%"), sep = "\n"), 
                y = Value), 
            size = 4, 
            vjust = "inward", 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  ggtitle("2016 V.S. 2017")  +
  labs(fill = "Catagory")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help!